# Combining expressions with a common operator

Tags: r

Let's say I have a collections of expressions

```
xx <- expression(5, sum(1:10), exp(2))
```

How can I join those into a single expression with a common operator between then, say `+` in this case? I'd like the result to be the (unevaluated) expression

```
5 + sum(1:10) + exp(2)
```

Ideally there's be some function like `paste` for expressions so I could call

```
paste_expr(xx, `+`)
```

It would be nice to avoid converting back to string and doing a potentially dangerous `paste()`

Comment: Not really my area of expertise but does `Reduce(function(x,y) call("+", x, y), xx)` do it?

Comment: @thelatemail  Ah yes. I thought this seemed liked a reduce operation but wasn’t sure what function would combine the two expressions. I think you are spot on with the call()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an attempt using `call` and `Reduce`:

```
Reduce(function(x,y) call("+", x, y), xx)
#5 + sum(1:10) + exp(2)
```

Seems to match what you want:

```
identical(Reduce(function(x,y) call("+", x, y), xx), join_exprs(xx))
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if such a function is built in, but using some `rlang` functions, you could make a function like

```
join_exprs <- function(exprs, op=`+`) {
  op <- ensym(op)
  N <- length(exprs)
  new_call <- exprs[[1]]
  for(x in exprs[-1]) {
    new_call <- expr((!!op)(!!new_call,!!x))
  }
  new_call
}

xx <- expression(5, sum(1:10), exp(2))
join_exprs(xx)
# 5 + sum(1:10) + exp(2)
```

Here we just do pairwise combining of the terms in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

The dangerous approach

```
parse(text = paste(lapply(xx, '['), collapse = " + "))
#expression(5 + sum(1:10) + exp(2))
```

Comment: why use `lapply`? `parse(text = paste(as.list(xx), collapse = " + "))` should be fine